# Load HTML code in ANDROID BROWSER

Tags: android, android-intent

```
String url = "<html><body>hello World</body></html>";
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(i);
```

how can i load the HTML source code in the browser? Please kindly explain with an example.

Answer (score 5):

```
Intent i = new Intent();

// MUST instantiate android browser, otherwise it won't work
i.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.browser", "com.android.browser.BrowserActivity"));
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

String html = "<html><body>hello World</body></html>";

// May work without url encoding, but I think is advisable
// URLEncoder.encode replace space with "+", must replace again with %20
String dataUri = "data:text/html," + URLEncoder.encode(html).replaceAll("\\+","%20");
i.setData(Uri.parse(dataUri));

startActivity(i);
```