# Force browser chooser when opening a local html file in Android

Tags: android, html, file, browser, local

Maybe this question or similar has been asked before, but I am really struggling for days now and couldn't find a precise answer and solution.. I have a local html file that I want to open with a browser chooser. So far I have this code:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + File.separator + "index/index.htm");
    Uri webPageUri = Uri.fromFile(file);


    browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    browserIntent.setDataAndType(webPageUri, "text/html");

  chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(browserIntent, "Choose your app:");

if (browserIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    startActivity(chooserIntent);
                }
```

which mostly gives me the html viewer and file/text editor as options. Additionally to this options, on some devices one browser option appears (for example opera).
How to tell the chooser that my file is an html file, and force the browser chooser?
Please share...

Answer (score 0):

Where's chooserIntent generated?

Replace

```
startActivity(whateverIntent)
```

with

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(browserIntent, "Open webpage using:"));
```

Comment: I am sorry I edited my code in the question I have that option as you can see in the update now

Comment: And that doesn't seem to help.. on some devices there is a one browser option (even though there are more installed) and on some device there is no browser option at all

Comment: On a button click the chooser activity opens and it shows only htmlviewer some file editor and for some reason it shows the opera browser if you have that one installed but no other browser installed is shown

Comment: Can confirm this behaviour. As soon as a .html comes from the file system Android browser and Chrome are absent. Firefox, Dolphin Browser and Opera are in. I wonder why the two main browsers are absent. It is not only your/my app. File explorers live with the same.

Comment: Does this help with some insight?(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644974/load-html-code-in-android-browser)